Adding custom underline for tabs
I've added a section which contain 3 tabs on my wordpress site using elementor. But I want to add a underline beneath the active tab. for example: https://calendly.com/
the one used in this site. Is there any option like that on elementor.

This sounds like a CSS issue or you'll have to open a ticket with Elementor.  Elementor is a third-party page builder that operates within WP, but it's not WP.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
